# Eclipse Android install Samsung Tab emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

How can I install Samsung Tab emulator? In my Android SDK manager there is no third-party link...

Do I need to download separately? And any working link to download Samsung Tab SDK?

Comment: meaningless question.. update your question for that we can understand what are you saying..

Comment: Do you want to test your app on Samsung Galaxy Tab Emulator ?

Comment: yes.. i want run my android application in sumsung tab for testing

Comment: You can go to this link http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Using-Samsung-Emulators-for-Android-Application-Development As Samsung offers real device emulator for testing android apps

Comment: Yes i know..it is not possible install in eclipse?

Comment: Samsung moves thier SDK and emulator which they shipped with Google Android SDK 8 months ago

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to download the skins from google.
To get the official Samsung Galaxy Tab emulator do the following:

```
Open the Android SDK and AVD Manager
Click on Available packages
Expand the Third party Add-ons. There you will see Samsung Electronics add-ons.
Once the add-on is installed create a new emulator. Under Target you will see the new Samsung Tab settings, select that.
```

That's it!

http://developer.samsung.com/home.do

Comment: i followed it already there is no "Third party Add-ons". my list showing 1. tools, 2.api 17, 3.android 4.1, etc.. and finally Extrass..

Comment: @user2444649 you can directly download the skins from google. search on google for "Galaxy Tab skins for android emulator" by this way you will get all kind devices skins